# Unable To Work Event Handler On AddEventListener Function

Tags: javascript, html, css, events

```js
let exitMenuBtn = document.querySelector(".fa-times");
let menuBtn = document.querySelector("#menu-btn");
console.log(menuBtn);

// Screen Elements
let sideBarMenu = document.querySelector("#menu");

menuBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked');
})
```

```css
div# menu - btn {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30 px;
  left: 30 px;
}

i.fa - bars {
  display: inline - block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu-btn">
  <i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" style="color: #9face6"></i>
</div>
```

I'm having a problem trying to the my event handler to work. Whenever i click on the menuBtn element nothing is happening at all. I have my script tags placed at the end of the html document.

Comment: Insert some text in the div and then click on the text.

Comment: ``<i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x" style="color: #9face6"></i>`` Use fontawesone CDN to get the icon, then when you click on the icon you will get ``clicked`` in console

Comment: You have spurious spaces in you CSS.